# Tasker: Detect ANT+ paired device, then switch on Endomondo

Tags: tasker

What will the Tasker Profile and Tasks look like when I want Endomondo app to launch as soon as my Note 3 detects a paired ANT+ device?

J

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell what it will look like (as I don't know all the details, e.g. your BT devices MAC), but I can show you the way to create such a profile:

- **Condition:** State → Bluetooth Connected (parameter: BT MAC of the ANT+ device)
- **Task:** Launch App (select Endomo)
- Worth reading: [Tasker User Guide](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/) (easy to look up things here ;)

Comment: Hi Izzy, ANT+ is a different protocol than Bluetooth. The Note 3 has sensors for both. I do not see a ANT+ connection state.

Comment: Ah – sorry for that, I wasn't aware of this fact. I don't own any ANT+ device, so I cannot check. In fact, "ANT+" doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere on the Tasker site. Maybe you contact the dev to ask? Either it's just missing in the docs, or it simply didn't yet make it to the TodoLists of the app …

Comment: Don't forget us with the results then :) Good luck so far!